# NoMethodError with Ruby when installing SoundCloud 2000 client for CLI

Tags: macos, command-line, ruby, rubygems, gem

I’m trying to install [SoundCloud2000](https://github.com/grobie/soundcloud2000) on my MacBook running Mac OS X 10.8.5.

I have Ruby 2.2.0, `mpg123`, and `portaudio` installed. Installing SoundCloud 2000 as a GEM seems to work fine:

```
gem install soundcloud2000
```

But then when I try to use it from the command line when I run—`$soundcloud2000`—I get the following error instead of the client:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/soundcloud2000-0.1.0/lib/soundcloud2000.rb:1: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/soundcloud2000-0.1.0/bin/soundcloud2000:3
    from /usr/bin/soundcloud2000:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/soundcloud2000:19
```

I don’t know what this means. Anyone else know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have Ruby 2.2.0 installed, but looking at the error all of the references are for `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/` which means SoundCloud 2000 is installed as a Ruby 1.8 GEM. So my guess is however you installed Ruby 2.2.0 that is not the main `ruby` you are running from the command line. You can confirm with version of Ruby you are running on your Mac by running this command:

```
ruby -v
```

The output should be something like this; note on I am running Mac OS X 10.9.5 so my installed version of Ruby will be higher than Mac OS X 10.8.5:

```
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
```

You can also see where your version of Ruby is being loaded from via [`which`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/which) like this:

```
which ruby
```

The output should be something like this:

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

The `which` tool tells you exactly what path the binary you are calling via that command is being loaded from.

Since it seems like you are using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to install a newer version of Rub, you need to also make sure your user’s `$PATH` is set to check `/usr/local/bin` before checking `/usr/bin`. This is typically set in the `.bash_profile` file in your home directory which is located via `~/.bash_profile`. Just note that this stuff might also be set in a file named `.bashc`, so adjust the examples to use `.bashc` instead of `.bash_profile` if that is the case.

For example, if I run the following command on my Mac OS X setup:

```
cat ~/.bash_profile
```

I see these contents:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin"
```

Might look complex, but it isn’t. All that command does is basically set the `$PATH` settings for your shell environment. And the items between the quotes are just directory paths separated by `:` characters. Of note to you this the order of `/usr/bin` versus `/usr/local/bin`; one comes in front of the other. Which basically means the system will check for `ruby` in `/usr/bin` and prefer to use that one before it even reaches the `ruby` installed via `/usr/local/bin`. So a quick fix for you would be to take `/usr/local/bin` and place it in front of `/usr/bin` via a text editor like `nano`. Then save it, exit your Terminal session and open a new one.

That said, if I were you I would recommend avoiding system level Ruby and Ruby GEM installs via Homebrew and rather use [RVM (Ruby Version Manager)](https://rvm.io) instead. Ruby—and Ruby GEMs—can actually be a pain to deal with on a good day; and even a worse of a headache on a Mac. So using RVM instead can allow you to create isolated Ruby and Ruby GEM installs specific to your user that are easier to manage.

I do Linux systems administration and tend to want to upgrade the version of Ruby installed by default and used to do that via source or package installers. But the more work I do on Ruby setups, the more I’ve realized that RVM is really the best way to install, manage and deal with Ruby setups. Slight learning/understanding curve when you first set it up but past that it will make your life—and system management—tons easier.

Comment: oh okay sorry about that, will do @jakegould

Comment: ahhh, excellent, that's the exact problem I'm having. Thank you so much for your help @jakegould, it is invaluable!!